# SpeechSynthesizer error in 'await' in windows phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, speechsynthesizer

I receive an error in SpeechSynthesizer, it says:

> Error: 'await' requires that the type 'Windows.Foundation.IAsynAction'
>   have a suitable GetAwaiter method. Are you missing directive for
>   'System'?

I use plain text, my code goes like this

```
await synth.SpeakTextAsync(titleTextBox.Text);
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `async` keyword to the method header.

```
    private async void MethodName()
    {
        var synth = new SpeechSynthesizer();
        await synth.SpeakTextAsync(titleTextBox.Text);
    }
```